# warning with gsoap

Tags: gsoap

I am using the gsoap library and when generating automatic code with the tools wsdl2h and soapcpp2 all work fine but when compiling thats code show a lot of warning as

```
warning: unused parameter 'soap'
```

on prototype as:

```
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_default_std__vectorTemplateOfPointerTodsca__FrameSequence(struct soap *soap, std::vector<dsca__FrameSequence * >*p)
```

and i don't know how fix it.

Thanks you very mmuch.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the warning, gSoap provides this parameter (gSoap stores it's runtime context in it) to you. Sometimes you have to use it, sometimes you don't need it. You have to use it, if you need to allocate memory for the response. Therefore gSoap provides the functions `soap_malloc(struct soap*, size_t num_bytes)` and `soap_new_YourClassName(struct soap*, int num_instances)`.